# Making a Multisite Dashboard Widget

Tags: multisite, widgets

I tried to use the code from this question: [How to Check Disk Space used by Media Library](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/67876)

But it's displaying this error in a Multisite:

[image: dashboard widget error]

How can I display it on my network Dashboard instead root site Dashboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a section in the dashboard w/ an input field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13236/how-do-i-create-a-section-in-the-dashboard-w-an-input-field)

Comment: my question is how can I display the widget on my network Dashboard instead root site Dashboard ! this is not resolved in any your links!

Answer (score 2):

You need the `wp_network_dashboard_setup` action instead of `wp_dashboard_setup`