# Can one display a specific page on the WordPress dashboard using the WordPress dashboard API?

Tags: dashboard

I'm using a WordPress page to display this week's notice. This page will need to be updated weekly. I would love to have a box on the WordPress dashboard (similar to QuickPress) that would allow the admin, to simply update the content easily.

I've added custom content on the dashboard before and I guess I could add a link to that page admin, but I'm not sure if I can add a box that would allow for this.
Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look to already existing WPSE answers -  like this one - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28412/14536

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Not sure why I couldn't find this earlier.